# Series about a planet-hopping aristocrat with a mechanical horse

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember a series of stories (I think there was 3-4 books in the series) about a planet hopping adventurer / lawman / aristocrat who had a mechanical horse called Fess or Fez (or something like that). The only thing I can remember is it suffered from seizures at the most inopportune moments.

Comment: LOL I immediately thought of BraveStarr.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wonder if this is the [Warlock of Gramarye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Stasheff#Warlock_of_Gramarye) series by Christopher Stasheff.

In the book [The Warlock in Spite of Himself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warlock_in_Spite_of_Himself) the hero Rod Gallowglass, an agent of an organisation called SCENT, is assisted by an AI called FCC 651919 that he calls *Fess* for short. Fess controls a mechanical horse and Rod rides this into various adventures, so it is sort of a lawman riding a mechanical horse called Fess.